# Find the equation of two ...

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Find the single equation of two straight lines that pass through the point $(2,3)$ and parallel to the line $x^2 - 6xy + 8y^2 = 0$.

My Attempt:

Let, $a_1x+b_1y=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y=0$ be the two lines represented by $x^2-6xy+8y^2=0$.
then,

$$(a_1x+b_1y)(a_2x+b_2y)=0$$
$$(a_1a_2)x^2+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)xy+(b_1b_2)y^2=0$$
Comparing with $x^2-6xy+8y^2=0$,

$a_1a_2=1, -(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)=6, b_1b_2=8$.

I got stuck at here. Please help me to continue this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $a_1a_2=1, -(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)=6, b_1b_2=8$.
>
> I got stuck at here. Please help me to continue this.

We may set $a_1=a_2=1$ to have
$$b_1+b_2=-6,\quad b_1b_2=8$$
giving $\{b_1,b_2\}=\{-2,-4\}$.

So, we get
$$x^2-6xy+8y^2=(x-2y)(x-4y)$$
Hence, the equation we want is
$$((x-2)-2(y-3))((x-2)-4(y-3))=0,$$
i.e.
$$(x-2y+4)(x-4y+10)=0$$

Comment: @user354073 : You may want to see [Horizontal translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_translation).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2-6xy+8y^2=(x-2y)(x-4y)$, so the lines represented by the equation $x^2-6xy+8y^2=0$ are
$$
x-2y=0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x - 4y = 0.
$$
The line parallel to $x-2y=0$ and passing through $(2,3)$ is 
$$
(x-2) - 2(y-3) =0,
$$
which in expanded form is $x - 2y + 4 = 0$. Similarly, the other line is $x-4y+10=0$. The single equation is then
$$
(x - 2y + 4)(x - 4y + 10) = 0.
$$

Comment: How did you get $(x-2)-2(y-3)=0$?

Comment: I just replaced $x$ by $x-2$ and $y$ by $y-3$ in the the ecuation $x-2y=0$. Think of it as a translation. You know that $x-2y=0$ is a line passing through the origin. Also, you want to obtain a straight line passing through $(2,3)$ but parallel to the given one. The geometric way of obtaining it is via a translation. You need to translate $(2,3)$ to $(0,0)$, so $(2,3)$ will be your new origin and the line will pass through it. How do we achieve a translation from $(2,3)$ to $(0,0)$? By mapping $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y) - (2,3)$, which is $(x-2,y-3)$. Then, we replace $x$ by $x-2$ and $y$ by $y-3$.

Comment: $x-4y+14=0$ does not pass through $(2,3)$.

Comment: Sorry, it was $x-4y+10$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The lines $$(x-2)^2 - 6(x-2)(y-3) + 8(y-3)^2 = 0$$ on transfer of origin to $(2,3)$, using the transformations $X = x-2, Y= y-2$ becomes $$X^2 - 6XY + 8Y^2 = 0$$ Hence the required equation is $$(x-2)^2 - 6(x-2)(y-3) + 8(y-3)^2 = 0$$

Comment: Is it necessary to take $-$ while transferring or can we take $+$, too?

Comment: If we have an equation $f(x,y) = 0$, and transfer the origin to $(h,k)$, the new equation is $f(X+h, Y+k) = 0$. In the present case, the equation $(x-2)^2 - 6(x-2)(y-3) + 8(y-3)^2 = 0$ when the origin is transferred to $(2,3)$ becomes $(X+2-2)^2 - 6(X+2-2)(Y+3-3) + 8(Y+3-3)^2 = 0$ and hence $X^2 -6XY + 8Y^2 = 0$ with reference to the new axes. This is what we have used.

Comment: What does $x$ , $X$, $y$, $Y$ represent?

Comment: $X, Y$ are the coordinates with respect to the new axes and $x,y$ are coordinates with respect to old axes.